# Лог для неудачного подключения к базе данных

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Я сделал лог, в который будет записываться ошибка подключения и сколько пользователей, получили эту ошибку.

Сделал вот так, пойдёт ли?

```
<?php

class DataBase {
    public static function connect ($host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.'; dbname='.$dbname.'; charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
        }

        catch (PDOException $e) {
            if(file_exists('error.txt')) {
                if($countError = file_get_contents('error.txt', NULL, NULL, 19, 2)) {
                    $countErrorFile = fopen('countError.txt', 'w');
                    fwrite($countErrorFile, $countError);

                    $readCountError = file_get_contents('countError.txt', NULL, NULL, 0, 2);

                    $fp = fopen('error.txt', 'w');
                    fwrite($fp, 'Count bad requests ');
                    fwrite($fp, $readCountError+1);
                    fwrite($fp, ' . Error = ');
                    fwrite($fp, $e->getMessage());
                }

                else {
                    $countError = file_get_contents('error.txt', NULL, NULL, 19, 2);
                    $fp = fopen('error.txt', 'w');
                }
            }
            else {
                $fp = fopen('error.txt', 'w');
                fwrite($fp, 'Count bad requests 1 ');
                fwrite($fp, $e->getMessage());

            }
            die('Не удалось подключиться к базе данных');
        }
        return $db;
    }
}
```

В файле, будет написано **Count bad requests 9 . Error = SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'faq'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

Цифра 9 означает, что 9 пользователей, не смогли подключится к базе, только я сделал счётчик до 100, в принципе, мне этого хватает, чтобы принять меры

Comment: а что вы собственно хотите?

Comment: совет, по улучшению кода

Comment: код работает нормально?

Comment: Работает нормально, но я его изменил, упростил конструкцию и теперь счётчик работает до бесконечности

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jMKVdLAy

Comment: ну так и не меняейте. Если работало, то верните как было. И всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы возложили лишнюю работу на скрипт и добавили в приложение так называемый **разделяемый ресурс** (countError) на жестком диске, который при нагрузке врятли будет достоверным, т.к. блокировки на файл нет, следовательно конкурирующие потоки могут писать разные числа. Конечно, в вашем случае данная информация не обязана быть достоверной, но следует учитывать это.

Я считаю, что не требуется писать в файл информацию о количестве ошибок. Это делает какой-нибудь лог скрипт с regexp или сервер логов (например greylog) с настроенными правилами, который анализирует ваш файл на подобные ошибки и отправляет их в slack, telegram, почту при наступлении определенного лимита сообщений.

Пишите в конец файла время и ошибку и анализируйте файл вручную или с помощью инструментов указанных выше. Пример формата:

```
[05-06-2017 13:52:51]  Access denied for user 'faq'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

С помощью различных инструментов командной строки файл можно легко проанилизировать и вытащить различные метрики. Для этого вам требуется почитать про tail, grep, awk, регулярные выражения.

Я не понимаю, почему вы вообще используете `w`, вместо того чтобы записывать в файл все ошибки, вы же теряете  **старые ошибки** базы данных при появлении новой. А их тьма!

Используйте флаг доступа `a` и записывайте ошибки в конец файла. [Вот тут подробнее.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php)

По коду очень много ошибок начинающего программиста:

- явное указание файла для ошибок в коде - нужно делать через конфигурацию.
- функция записи напрямую определена в catch и не сделана через какой-нибудь класс logger, следовательно в приложении где-то есть уже подобный код и значит он дублируется, в связи с чем нарушается одно из ключевых принципов DRY (Don’t repeat yourself)
- излишнее количество вызов fwrite, где это можно обьединить в одну строку.